# External JavaScript file not working and code not loading

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript ES6 and struggling to get my external script.js file to work. This is  my first time trying to connect an external JavaScript file. I added the script tag just before closing the body tag. When I try to test it by opening the code with the live server, I do not see any of the changes I made. I think the external JS file is not connecting properly. The code in there does not seem to be picked up at all. Please advise how I can fix this.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Restaurant menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="menuContainer">
    <div class="menuBox">
    <h1 id="item">Food Item1
    </h1>
    <p id="oneLiner">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.
    </p>
         <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/delicious-fried-chicken-plate_144627-27383.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.404766179.1658308353" alt="img" id="img">

         <h2 id="hotel">Hotel name1

         </h2>
         <p id="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?

         </p>
        
         <div class="btn">
            <button id="prev"><img src=https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtb_on3v-MaK_PJ7IQW4odw2kfxHc9Tw_GkQ&usqp=CAU> </button>
            <button id="random">Random Menu</button>
             <button id="next">:arrrow </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
const menuItems=[
    {
        id:1,
        item:"Food Item1",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/delicious-fried-chicken-plate_144627-27383.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.404766179.1658308353" alt="img" id="img",
         hotel:"Hotel name1",
         desc:"One:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
    {
        id:2,
        item:"Food Item2",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/delicious-food-white-plate_144627-34705.jpg?w=996&t=st=1658479142~exp=1658479742~hmac=01dc2417f561f6c0f085dd950329cc540c80708a855036bb20742a6a07045854",
         hotel:"Hotel name2",
         desc:"Two:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
    {
        id:3,
        item:"Food Item3",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/flat-lay-salad-with-chicken-sesame-seeds_23-2148700369.jpg?t=st=1658479233~exp=1658479833~hmac=923cf6d606b47745be064daefd12de3c39795a3cd294267bb1eeb76f4fd1bc06&w=996",
         hotel:"Hotel name3",
         desc:"Three:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
    {
        id:4,
        item:"Food Item4",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/top-view-delicious-autumn-soup-composition_23-2148634470.jpg?t=st=1658479312~exp=1658479912~hmac=d46be965f48809c72046fca1aba514a39f16e26d4512c8c52c50b40d7d050b4a&w=996",
         hotel:"Hotel name4",
         desc:"Four:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
    {
        id:5,
        item:"Food Item5",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/concept-tasty-food-with-beef-with-vegetables-close-up_185193-75830.jpg?t=st=1658479413~exp=1658480013~hmac=62bbb71751e0b62e1aab4542bc09efefa4cde3eca56680c250164c6047304ed0&w=996",
         hotel:"Hotel name5",
         desc:"Five:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
]

const item=document.getElementById('item');
const oneLiner=document.getElementById('oneLiner');
const img=document.getElementById('img');
const hotel=document.getElementById('hotel');
const desc=document.getElementById('desc');
const prev=document.getElementById('prev');
const random=document.getElementById('random');
const next=document.getElementById('next');

let currentMenu=1;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    let menu=menuItems[currentMenu];
    item.textContent=menu.item;
    oneLiner.textContent=menu.oneLiner;
    img.src=menu.img;
    hotel.textContent=menu.hotel;
    desc.textContent=menu.desc;

});
```

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is a request made for `script.js`?  What is the server's response?

Comment: Inspect the page and check Sources to see if your javascript is loaded at all

Comment: I don't see any request for script.js only for index.html and style.css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your index, CSS, and js file are in the same folder.

I have made changes in your js code also please have a look.

```js
const menuItems=[
    {
        id:1,
        item:"Food Item1",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/delicious-fried-chicken-plate_144627-27383.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.404766179.1658308353", alt:"img", id:"img",
         hotel:"Hotel name1",
         desc:"One:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
    {
        id:2,
        item:"Food Item2",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/delicious-food-white-plate_144627-34705.jpg?w=996&t=st=1658479142~exp=1658479742~hmac=01dc2417f561f6c0f085dd950329cc540c80708a855036bb20742a6a07045854",
         hotel:"Hotel name2",
         desc:"Two:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
    {
        id:3,
        item:"Food Item3",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/flat-lay-salad-with-chicken-sesame-seeds_23-2148700369.jpg?t=st=1658479233~exp=1658479833~hmac=923cf6d606b47745be064daefd12de3c39795a3cd294267bb1eeb76f4fd1bc06&w=996",
         hotel:"Hotel name3",
         desc:"Three:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
    {
        id:4,
        item:"Food Item4",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/top-view-delicious-autumn-soup-composition_23-2148634470.jpg?t=st=1658479312~exp=1658479912~hmac=d46be965f48809c72046fca1aba514a39f16e26d4512c8c52c50b40d7d050b4a&w=996",
         hotel:"Hotel name4",
         desc:"Four:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
    {
        id:5,
        item:"Food Item5",
        oneliner:"Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.",
         img:"https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/concept-tasty-food-with-beef-with-vegetables-close-up_185193-75830.jpg?t=st=1658479413~exp=1658480013~hmac=62bbb71751e0b62e1aab4542bc09efefa4cde3eca56680c250164c6047304ed0&w=996",
         hotel:"Hotel name5",
         desc:"Five:Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?",

    },
]
console.log("in script");
const item=document.getElementById('item');
const oneLiner=document.getElementById('oneLiner');
const img=document.getElementById('img');
const hotel=document.getElementById('hotel');
const desc=document.getElementById('desc');
const prev=document.getElementById('prev');
const random=document.getElementById('random');
const next=document.getElementById('next');

let currentMenu=1;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    let menu=menuItems[currentMenu];
    item.textContent=menu.item;
    oneLiner.textContent=menu.oneLiner;
    img.src=menu.img;
    hotel.textContent=menu.hotel;
    desc.textContent=menu.desc;

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Restaurant menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<div class="menuContainer">
    <div class="menuBox">
    <h1 id="item">Food Item1
    </h1>
    <p id="oneLiner">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis, ab.
    </p>
         <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/delicious-fried-chicken-plate_144627-27383.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.404766179.1658308353" alt="img" id="img">

         <h2 id="hotel">Hotel name1

         </h2>
         <p id="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid deserunt pariatur dolorem quo necessitatibus quas voluptatibus eaque placeat soluta voluptatem?

         </p>
        
         <div class="btn">
            <button id="prev"><img src=https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtb_on3v-MaK_PJ7IQW4odw2kfxHc9Tw_GkQ&usqp=CAU> </button>
            <button id="random">Random Menu</button>
             <button id="next">:arrrow </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem definitely seems to be coming from the script path.

You wrote this:

`<script src="script.js"></script>`

So I assume that `script.js` lives in the same directory as your `index.html`

```
root
    |   index.html
    |   script.js
```

You could try to write it this way:

`<script src="./script.js"></script>`

Without knowing your directories structure I cannot give you the right answer.

As others pointed out,  you can have a hint on whether the file was successfully loaded or not inside your dev tool network tab.

It is recommended to you use some add-on that can autocomplete the path for you within your IDE.
For example with VS Code, you can use [path-intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense)